# Customize the Error Message for an invalid date in ASP.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-validation

I have an ASP.net MVC model with a date:

```
public class EditModel
{ 
    [Display(Name="DOB")]
    public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }
}

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DateOfBirth)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.DateOfBirth)
```

When the user enters an invalid date such as 9/31/2011, the error message comes back as this:

`The value '9/31/2011' is not valid for DOB.`

This is happening when it is trying to do the model binding and is not one of my validations. Is there a way to customize this error message? I would like it to be something like:

`Please enter a valid date for the Date of Birth.`

I am not requiring the user to enter the Date, but when they do enter an INVALID value then I want to customize the error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this,

```
[DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid date.")]
public System.DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
```

Hope this will help you.. :)

Answer (score 5):

You can use data annotations for errors, or, in this case you can do this:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.DateOfBirth , "Please enter a valid date for the Date of Birth.")
```

Comment: This would change it for all errors. I have other validations that I don't want to override. Also, I am currently using this because I want to display a * next to the text box and use the validation summary to show the full error.

Comment: Then write a custom validator for it and put the message about the invalid date with that validator.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class myClass()
{

    [Display(Name="Date of Birth"), DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid date for the Date of Birth.")]
    public string dateOfBirth { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: FYI, it seems that ErrorMessage is ignored with the DataType attribute. It does show an error message, but not the one specified in the ErrorMessage parameter. See [MVC Datatype ErrorMessage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13916991/mvc-datatype-errormessage).

Answer (score 0):

With me error message in datatype not work
**Remove it** using regular

```
[Display(Name="Date of Birth")]
[RegularExpression(@"^(3[01]|[12][0-9]|0[1-9])[-/](1[0-2]|0[1-9])[-/][0-9]{4}$", ErrorMessageResourceName = "DateNotValid", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources))]
    public string dateOfBirth { get; set; }
```

DateNotValid : is using in resource file. you can change to error message if you want
the format above for: dd-MM-YYYYY