# MVC Datatype ErrorMessage

Tags: asp.net-mvc

DataType ErrorMessage doesn't work.
MVC4 DataType ErrorMessage doesn't seem to work.
I have this dataannotation Attribute:

```
[DataType(DataType.DateTime, ErrorMessage = "Invalid date")]
public override DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; }
```

but client validation return this error:

The field BirthDate must be a date.

this is the Html portion:

```
 <input Value="" class="date" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field BirthDate  must be a date." data-val-required="El campo Fecha nacimiento es obligatorio" id="Patient_BirthDate" name="Patient.BirthDate" type="text" value="" />
```

Any idea?

Comment: possible duplicate of [DataTypeAttribute is showing the wrong message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10028384/datatypeattribute-is-showing-the-wrong-message)

Comment: Thank Archil but wath's the mining of ErrorMessage? Also, why the attribute  [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Messages.GeneralMessages), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required")] work properly ?

Comment: I got it, in MVC 4 is possible to localize default error message. [link](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2013/03/31/localizing-default-error-messages-in-asp-net-mvc-and-web-form.aspxm)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Short Answer:** Purpose of `DataType.DateTime` is NOT to validate your `DateTime` entry for Birthday property. This is the reason. What it does is just formats the DateTime before displaying it on your view.

What you need is to have `[Required]` attribute on top of that as well.

However, what **i usually prefer to use** is [**Jquery Datepicker**](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/)  and it doesn't even allow user to enter any text, but a valid date.

**Edit:** When you decorate a model property with `[DataType(DataType.Date)]` the default template in ASP.NET MVC 4 generates an input field of type="date". Browsers that support HTML5 such Google Chrome render this input field with a date picker.

You may enforce this with code:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; }
```

In order to correctly display the date, the value must be formatted as `2012-09-28`

Comment: Ok, it make sense, but wath's the mining of ErrorMessage?

Comment: When you decorate a model property with [DataType(DataType.Date)] the default template in ASP.NET MVC 4 generates an input field of type="date". Browsers that support HTML5 such Google Chrome render this input field with a date picker.

In order to correctly display the date, the value must be formatted as 2012-09-28

Comment: i have updated my answer with a sample and more explanations.

Comment: ok, thank you ElYusubov, after dome research i discovered that this message is internal from Framework, so the only solution is to implement a custom validation.

Answer (score 8):

On MVC 4 I was able to change the error message in the View with Html.ValidationMessageFor.

See an example:`@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FechaDesde, "Fecha Inválida")`

Comment: Problem I've found with this is that it displays the error regardless of whether the data is valid or not.