# Change DateTime error message

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I use MVC 5 and in my model I have DateTime property like this:

```
[Column(TypeName = "Date")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
```

when I entered an invalid date the following message appears in ValidationSummary:

> The field StartDate must be a date

I need to change this message where I can change it?

Answer (score 4):

You need to add `ErrorMessage` property .Try this

```
[DataType(DataType.Date),ErrorMessage="Your message here"]
```

Comment: It looks obvious, but that doesn't work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13916991/mvc-datatype-errormessage

Comment: @CodeCaster yes ErrorMessage doesn't work with me, but the link you sent didn't help me as well please I need more clarification what is the use of ErrorMessage in DataType and how can I override this default message

Comment: @AbrahamJosef scroll down a bit to the next answer in that link that CodeCaster provided. It shows how you can use [`ValidationMessageFor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703502(v=vs.118).aspx). Hth...

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was adding a data-val-date attribute to the textbox to override the one that gets created for it (inspect the textbox and you'll see).

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DateOfBirth, new { @class = "form-control", inputDate = "", data_val_date = "Please enter a valid date" })
```

Answer (score 0):

From razor you can do this in this way.

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StartDate, "Your custom message.", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

Comment: When I do that, the message always shows, regardless of whether the data is valid or not.